# Visual Studio freeze on opening projects

Tags: asp.net

I am using visual studio 2015 but of late the IDE has been freezing on opening projects. Is there a way to uninstall installed plugins or any solution whatsoever.

Comment: Have you tried running in safe mode? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-sysrequirements-vs) are the Visual Studio's 2015 requirements (in case your computer can not handle the IDE) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd293639(v=vs.100).aspx) is the way to remove Visual Studio Tools and extensions.

Comment: Thanks. However I uninstalled some plugins and it worked again